# How to redirect to the page which shows only the data inserted to the database from that id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

For example if there is a form which creates customers, and when you filled the form and submit the page should redirect and show the data which was inserted to that form by a specific individual id. in my case it redirects to a page and views all the data in the database.

Here's my `Web.php`

```
Route::get('customers','CustomersController@index');
Route::get('customers/create','CustomersController@create');
Route::post('customers','CustomersController@store');
Route::get('customers/{customer}','CustomersController@show');
```

Here's my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Customer;

use App\Company;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $customers = Customer::all();

        return view('customers.index',compact('customers'));

    }

    public function create(){

        $companies = Company::all();

        return view ('customers.create',compact('companies'));
    }

    public function store()
    {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'name'=>'required | min:3',
            'email'=>'required | email',
            'active'=>'required ',
            'company_id'=>'required',
        ]);



        Customer::create($data);

        return redirect('customers');
    }

    // * Route Model binding
    public function show(Customer $customer){

        return view('customers.show',compact('customer'));
    }
}
```

Here's my `Customer Model`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];


    public function getActiveAttribute($attribute){
        return [
            0 => 'Inactive',
            1 => 'Active',
        ] [$attribute];
    }

    public function scopeActive($query){
        return $query->where('active',1);
    }

    public function scopeInactive($query){
        return $query->where('active',0);
    }

      public function company()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
      }
}
```

Here's my `Create Blade`

```
@extends('layouts')

@section('title','Add New Customer')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Add New Customer</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form action="/customers" method="POST" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{old('name')}}">
            <div>{{$errors->first('name')}}</div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}">
            <div>{{$errors->first('email')}}</div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Customer Status</label>
              <select name="active" id="active" class=" form-control">
                  <option value="" disabled>Select Customer Status</option>
                  <option value="1">Active</option>
                  <option value="0">Inactive</option>
              </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="company_id">Company</label>
              <select name="company_id" id="company_id" class=" form-control">
                  @foreach ($companies as $company)
                      <option value="{{ $company->id }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-dark">Add Customer</button>
          @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here's my `show blade`

```
@extends('layouts')

@section('title','Details for ' . $customer->name)

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Details for {{ $customer->name }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p><strong>Name : </strong> {{ $customer->name }}</p>
      <p><strong>Email : </strong> {{ $customer->email }}</p>
      <p><strong>Company : </strong> {{ $customer->company->name }}</p>
      <p><strong>Status : </strong> {{ $customer->active }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I am not pretty sure you want to show the data that just got submitted in the form or you want to show those data which is submitted by the current users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to the `show` route rather than the customers `index` route:

```
$customer = Customer::create($data);

return redirect('customers/' . $customer->id);
```